# SQL query over partition with condition

Tags: sql, window-functions, partition-by

I have a table like this, in SQL Server 2019:

| ITEM_ID | Parent_Item | Talle | Existencia |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 909296 | 280647 | 4 | 1 |
| 909296 | 280647 | 4 | 1 |
| 909296 | 280647 | 4 | 1 |
| 909297 | 280647 | 5 | 1 |
| 909297 | 280647 | 5 | 1 |
| 909297 | 280647 | 5 | 1 |
| 909297 | 280647 | 5 | 1 |
| 909298 | 280647 | 6 | 1 |
| 909298 | 280647 | 6 | 1 |
| 909298 | 280647 | 6 | 1 |
| 909299 | 280647 | 7 | 1 |
| 909299 | 280647 | 7 | 1 |
| 909300 | 280647 | 8 | 1 |
| 909301 | 280647 | 9 | 1 |
| 909293 | 280647 | 11 | 1 |
| 909294 | 280647 | 12 | 1 |
| 909292 | 280647 | 10 | 1 |
| 1226447 | 280647 | 13 | 0 |

And I need a new column named 'Real Exist.' with the total sum of different values in 'Talle' Column, when 'Existencia' = 1. In this example (Parent_item = 280647) result should be 9 , because of values 4,5,6,7,8,9,11, 12, 10 in 'Talle' Column :

| ITEM_ID | Parent_Item | Talle | Existencia | Real Exist. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 909296 | 280647 | 4 | 1 | 9 |
| 909296 | 280647 | 4 | 1 | 9 |
| 909296 | 280647 | 4 | 1 | 9 |
| 909297 | 280647 | 5 | 1 | 9 |
| 909297 | 280647 | 5 | 1 | 9 |
| 909297 | 280647 | 5 | 1 | 9 |
| 909297 | 280647 | 5 | 1 | 9 |
| 909298 | 280647 | 6 | 1 | 9 |
| 909298 | 280647 | 6 | 1 | 9 |
| 909298 | 280647 | 6 | 1 | 9 |
| 909299 | 280647 | 7 | 1 | 9 |
| 909299 | 280647 | 7 | 1 | 9 |
| 909300 | 280647 | 8 | 1 | 9 |
| 909301 | 280647 | 9 | 1 | 9 |
| 909293 | 280647 | 11 | 1 | 9 |
| 909294 | 280647 | 12 | 1 | 9 |
| 909292 | 280647 | 10 | 1 | 9 |
| 1226447 | 280647 | 13 | 0 | 9 |

How could it be done?. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: select #tbl_catalogo.*, 
Sum(Existencia) OVER(PARTITION BY Parent_Item, Calidad_id) as Curva_Real
I´m a beginner, I don´t know how to do it...Looked for solutions in posts, but can´t solve it...thanks for the help

Comment: Please put that in you question, not in the comments.

Comment: Sounds like you mean count of *unique values* rather than SUM. Also, *always* include your dbms and version in the question tags.

Comment: Done!. SQL server 2019. yes...the unique values is what I need...

Comment: I don't think window functions are the right tool for a unique values query. See the suggestion below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is using a derived query to count the number of unique values per Parent_Item

```
SELECT yt.Item_Id
       , yt.Parent_Item
       , yt.Talle
       , yt.Existencia
       , cnt.NumOfTalle AS [Real Exist]
FROM   YourTable yt 
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT Parent_Item, COUNT(DISTINCT Talle) AS NumOfTalle
            FROM   YourTable
            WHERE  Existencia = 1
            GROUP  BY Parent_Item
        ) 
        cnt ON cnt.Parent_Item = yt.Parent_Item
```

**Results:**

> ```
> Item_Id | Parent_Item | Talle | Existencia | Real Exist
> ------: | ----------: | ----: | ---------: | ---------:
>  909296 |      280647 |     4 |          1 |          9
>  909296 |      280647 |     4 |          1 |          9
>  909296 |      280647 |     4 |          1 |          9
>  909297 |      280647 |     5 |          1 |          9
>  909297 |      280647 |     5 |          1 |          9
>  909297 |      280647 |     5 |          1 |          9
>  909297 |      280647 |     5 |          1 |          9
>  909298 |      280647 |     6 |          1 |          9
>  909298 |      280647 |     6 |          1 |          9
>  909298 |      280647 |     6 |          1 |          9
>  909299 |      280647 |     7 |          1 |          9
>  909299 |      280647 |     7 |          1 |          9
>  909300 |      280647 |     8 |          1 |          9
>  909301 |      280647 |     9 |          1 |          9
>  909293 |      280647 |    11 |          1 |          9
>  909294 |      280647 |    12 |          1 |          9
>  909292 |      280647 |    10 |          1 |          9
> 1226447 |      280647 |    13 |          0 |          9
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=89a6e86bcbf43bafaf4be7a082dbb9c4)*